# Filter only EQUAL values into columns with dplyr::filter_if

Tags: r

I have following data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3), 
  y = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3)
)
```

I try use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter_if(~ is.numeric(.), all_vars(. %in% c('3', '4')))

  x y
1 4 3
2 3 4
3 4 4
4 3 3
```

But, the expected result is:

```
  x y
1 3 3
2 4 4
```

How do this?

Comment: You can just do `df %>%
 filter(x == y)`.

Comment: How apply in the `filter_if` (only numeric columns)? I try this `df %>% 
  filter_if(~ is.numeric(.), all_vars(. == .))`. But, doesn't work.  I can't use variables names (`x` and `y`), only your classes.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3), 
  y = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3),
  z = letters[1:6]
)

df %>%
  filter(apply(.,1,function(x) length(unique(x[grepl('[0-9]',x)]))==1))
```

gives:

```
  x y z
1 4 4 d
2 3 3 f
```

I have added a non-numeric column to the example data, to illustrate this solution.

Comment: Thanks @Wietze314. But, I need a solution with `filter_if`.

Comment: I think `filter_if` evaluates each value per row separately, so you are not able to evaluate the context of these values (i.e. compare values within its row). That is why I don't think you can do this with `filter_if` and why I used `filter` and `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a `filter_if()` possibility, but essentially following that logic:

```
df %>%       
 filter(rowMeans(select_if(., is.numeric) == pmax(!!!select_if(., is.numeric))) == 1)

  x y z
1 4 4 d
2 3 3 f
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3), 
                 y = c(2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3),
                 z = letters[1:6],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```